# Link between graphical interface an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, user-interface, prototype, libraries

I am coding a small library in javascript. Here is my problem:

- I created a new type "**Student**" with some param such as "**name**", "**age**", "**level**", "**grade**", etc.
- I would like to create a display function to modify a variable of "**Student**" type. It will load in the page a HTML Form.
- Finally as the user modifies the form the variable "**Student**" should be changed too.

What is a good method to achieve this?

Comment: And what do you want to do with the Student data?

Comment: If on a page I want to display 10 students, and I need to modify one, I will call `var s1 = new Student();` 

`s1.editfunction();`

It will open a Form. And every modification made on this Form will be applied to `s1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a allready a great lib for this. Called AngularJS.

- create a form
- create Student and keep reference to the DOM element which represents that student, or create the html elements when creating a new instance of the Student.
- update changes in DOM when submitting the form. And notify a StudentObserver to update the data.

Comment: Thx, this seems to be what I need. I'm going to look into it.